# How can I parse data from a JSON file into a new GeoJSON in Kotlin?

Tags: javascript, json, kotlin, parsing, geojson

I am completely new to Kotlin and I have a task that I am trying to perform and cannot seem to find much documentation. I have coded what I need to do in JavaScript (see below), but I need to convert the same functionality to Kotlin. Basically, I have JSON file that contains coordinates within it. I need to extract these coordinates and push them into a brand new GeoJson variable. This is the code I need to convert, how can I go about doing this?

```
let routeTemp = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': []
}

let geoTemp = {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {},
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': [],
        }
    };

function jsonToGeo(data) {
    for(track in data.track) {
        let coords = [data.track[track].Lon, data.track[track].Lat];
        geoTemp.geometry['coordinates'].push(coords);
    }
    routeTemp['features'].push(geoTemp);
}
```

Comment: What platform are you targetting ? Kotlin JVM or Kotlin JS ? For GeoJson, I know only JVM based libraries. You might want to look at kotlinx.serialization library which works on all platforms and allow to read and write Json.

Comment: Hello, have you found the solution?

Comment: @Tommy just posted what I came up with for you to check out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution I ended up coming up with...

Make sure to import this:

```
import org.json.JSONObject
```

I defined my JSON as a string globally, and then used it to construct a JSON Object:

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonStr) // convert JSON string into JSON Object
```

Include this in the onCreate function:

```
val coordsLine =  parseJsonL()
val  geoStr = geoTemp(coordsLine)
```

Then define these functions:

```
// function to parse line coordinates from JSON
fun parseJsonL(): ArrayList<String> {
    // extract tracks as an array from JSON
    val trackArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("track")
    val coordList = ArrayList<String>()
    // iterate through coordinates for each track, extract as strings, and add to a list
    for (i in 0 until trackArray.length()) {
        val coordsL = trackArray.getJSONObject(i)
        val lon = coordsL.getString("Lon")
        val lat = coordsL.getString("Lat")
        coordList.add("[$lon, $lat]")
    }
    return coordList
}

// function to insert coordinates into GeoJSON template
fun geoTemp(coordsLine: ArrayList<String>): String {
    val geoStr = """
            {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": "Sea Wall Route"
                        },
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "LineString",
                            "coordinates": $coordsLine
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        """.trimIndent()
    return geoStr
}
```

I'm open to suggestions for improving this code since, again, I'm very new to Kotlin :)

Comment: Hello @BriannaDrew Thanks for the response, someone actually answered to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77378653/how-to-create-geojson-file-in-kotlin/77378860?noredirect=1#comment136415489_77378860

Do you know how to download the GeoJSON file that has been created?