# How to create GeoJson file in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, geospatial, polygon, geojson

Let's say I have a polygon of a farm with the following coordinates:

```
1st coordinate: lat: 4.5165132153 long: 99.651681683
2nd coordinate: lat: 4.5163152153 long: 99.878981683
3rd coordinate: lat: 4.3584532153 long: 99.021481683
4th coordinate: lat: 4.1578132153 long: 99.698781683
5th coordinate: lat: 4.3655132153 long: 99.321481683
6th coordinate: lat: 4.8795132153 long: 99.874581683
```

How can I create a GeoJSON file and then download the created GeoJSON file after clicking a button?

```
binding.downloadGeojsonFileButton.setOnClickListener{
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Where would the file be created and by who? Downloading from a server on the internet?

Comment: the file will be saved in the phone's storage by the app user. The coordinate will be retrieved from the app's asset.

Comment: Sorry you did not answer any of my three questions. Which app to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create and download a GeoJSON file, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a GeoJSON feature with your polygon coordinates using standard JSON manipulation:

```kotlin
val coordinates = listOf(
    Coordinate(4.5165132153, 99.651681683),
    Coordinate(4.5163152153, 99.878981683),
    Coordinate(4.3584532153, 99.021481683),
    Coordinate(4.1578132153, 99.698781683),
    Coordinate(4.3655132153, 99.321481683),
    Coordinate(4.8795132153, 99.874581683)
)

val geometry = mapOf(
    "type" to "Polygon",
    "coordinates" to listOf(listOf(coordinates.map { listOf(it.lon, it.lat) }))
)

val properties = mapOf(
    "name" to "Your Polygon Name",
    // Add other properties as needed
)

val feature = mapOf(
    "type" to "Feature",
    "geometry" to geometry,
    "properties" to properties
)

val featureCollection = mapOf(
    "type" to "FeatureCollection",
    "features" to listOf(feature)
)
```

2. Serialize the GeoJSON data to a JSON string:

```kotlin
val gson = Gson()
val geoJsonString = gson.toJson(featureCollection)
```

3. To download the GeoJSON file, you can write the JSON string to a file in the app's internal storage:

```kotlin
val fileName = "my_polygon.geojson"
val file = File(context.filesDir, fileName)

file.writeText(geoJsonString)
```

4. To allow the user to download the GeoJSON file, you can create a button click listener that provides a download link to the user:

```kotlin
binding.downloadGeojsonFileButton.setOnClickListener {
    val file = File(context.filesDir, "my_polygon.geojson")

    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        "${context.packageName}.provider",
        file
    )

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        data = uri
        flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        type = "application/json"
    }

    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

5. Define a File Provider in your AndroidManifest.xml file and create a `file_paths.xml` file as mentioned in the previous response.

This approach allows you to create and download a GeoJSON file without using third-party libraries by manually constructing the GeoJSON structure using standard JSON manipulation techniques.

Comment: How can you group the lat and long inside the Coordinate()? It seems there is no Coordinate() function in Kotlin.

Comment: create a class, data class Coordinate(val lat: Double, val lon: Double)