# How to download GeoJSON file in Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-manifest, geojson

So the GeoJSON file will be created with the following code:

```
val coordinates = listOf(
Coordinate(4.5165132153, 99.651681683),
Coordinate(4.5163152153, 99.878981683),
Coordinate(4.3584532153, 99.021481683),
Coordinate(4.1578132153, 99.698781683),
Coordinate(4.3655132153, 99.321481683),
Coordinate(4.8795132153, 99.874581683)
)

val geometry = mapOf(
    "type" to "Polygon",
    "coordinates" to listOf(listOf(coordinates.map { listOf(it.lon, it.lat) }))
)

val properties = mapOf(
    "name" to "Your Polygon Name",
    // Add other properties as needed
)

val feature = mapOf(
    "type" to "Feature",
    "geometry" to geometry,
    "properties" to properties
)

val featureCollection = mapOf(
    "type" to "FeatureCollection",
    "features" to listOf(feature)
)
```

Then serialise the GeoJSON data into JSON string

```
val gson = Gson()
val geoJsonString = gson.toJson(featureCollection)
```

Then write the JSON string in the app's internal storage

```
val fileName = "my_polygon.geojson"
val file = File(context.filesDir, fileName)

file.writeText(geoJsonString)
```

So I would like to download this data and save it into the phone storage by clickling a button, for example: binding.downloadButton.setOnClickListener{ }

Does anyone know how to perform this task?

Thank you!

Comment: Where would you download the data from? Where is it?

Comment: Your learned nothing from your earlier post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77378653/how-to-create-geojson-file-in-kotlin

Comment: @blackapps Hi, sorry I didnt understand how to explain before, but now I think the GeoJSON file will be stored in the internal app storage. Or if you have other idea on how to create the GeoJSON file then download it to the device storage, that will be the best.

Comment: You still talk about downloading. Sigh.. if you created the geojson data then you could save that data to a file in storage. There is nothing to download as downloading would be done from internet or another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define the required `permissions`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Check `permissions`.

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
       == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    requestPermissions(
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
        PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
    )
}
```

And save file operation

```
try {
    val root =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkDirs()
    }
    val file = File(root, "fileName.json")
    val writer = FileWriter(file)
    writer.append(geoJsonString)
    writer.flush()
    writer.close()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

**Your case**

```
binding.downloadButton.setOnClickListener {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
        )
    } else {
        try {
            val root =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs()
            }
            val file = File(root, "fileName.json")
            val writer = FileWriter(file)
            writer.append(geoJsonString)
            writer.flush()
            writer.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! thanks! but for android v33 and later, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not allowed, what is the alternative permission for this sir? Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome. İ recomended https://youtu.be/dEASm7nv7DA?si=WyYfDqjmlnbkBO50